# ActiveRecord doesn't save valid attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem. I'm trying to save a user using console but it doesn't work and I cannot figure what's the issue.

Here is the log:

```
2.0.0-p353 :095 >   u = User.find_by_email('xxxx@gmail.com')
 => #<User id: 5359, created_at: "2012-01-14 12:39:01", updated_at: "2014-07-04 09:48:06", email: "xxxx@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "xxxx.", role_id: nil, reset_password_token: "xxxx...", reset_password_sent_at: "2014-07-02 15:21:06", remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmed_at: "2014-07-04 09:46:08", confirmation_sent_at: nil, confirmation_token: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, legacy_pass: "xxxxx", username: "Mr. Brightside", discourse_id: nil, my_draft_comments_count: 0, my_published_comments_count: 37, my_comments_count: 37, draft_comcoms_count: 0, published_comcoms_count: 0, deleted_comcoms_count: 0, spam_comcoms_count: 0, mailchimped: false, slug: "mr-brightside", accept_rules: true, accept_privacy: true>
2.0.0-p353 :096 > u.username = 'brightside'
 => "brightside"
2.0.0-p353 :097 > u.valid?
 => true
2.0.0-p353 :098 > u.save!
 => true
2.0.0-p353 :099 > u
 => #<User id: 5359, created_at: "2012-01-14 12:39:01", updated_at: "2014-07-04 09:48:06", email: "xxxx@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$10$CdvtY4/TnwTpzDKJdFv/HOoQmIemvWfltrrqluWH.8qf...", role_id: nil, reset_password_token: "be7b04448caaf9a59a1204a6d2605b0f7257d9a8c8d5d08fa73...", reset_password_sent_at: "2014-07-02 15:21:06", remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 0, current_sign_in_at: nil, last_sign_in_at: nil, current_sign_in_ip: nil, last_sign_in_ip: nil, confirmed_at: "2014-07-04 09:46:08", confirmation_sent_at: nil, confirmation_token: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, legacy_pass: "bf59677e3dfb10370293efb5568f1a37", username: "Mr. Brightside", discourse_id: nil, my_draft_comments_count: 0, my_published_comments_count: 37, my_comments_count: 37, draft_comcoms_count: 0, published_comcoms_count: 0, deleted_comcoms_count: 0, spam_comcoms_count: 0, mailchimped: false, slug: "mr-brightside", accept_rules: true, accept_privacy: true>
2.0.0-p353 :100 >
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you see proper sql queries executed in console?

Comment: @SunnyMagadan I'm in production... no sql query

Comment: Why / how is the user's email different after your save? It goes from `xxxx@gmail.com` to `andysal@gmail.com`. Do you have any callbacks before your save in your code?

Comment: No ideas. Seems that it should work. Do you have ability to run console in development env on the same database?

Comment: @tirdadc my fault, i edited the real email and I forgot the last one, please remove that email from your comment. 

I'm using devise.

Comment: Can you post your `User` model code, please?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-save-21) for `save!`:

> Attributes marked as readonly are silently ignored if the record is being updated.

So check if that's the case. Otherwise it should work as expected.

Also, to inspect the actually saved record from the DB, in your console you might have to call `u.reload`. The object you're inspecting in the last line has the same `updated_at` timestamp as the original, so either it didn't update at all, or it wasn't reloaded from the DB (unless you type reaaaaally fast).